# UV Project Modifier in Cycles has no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, modifiers

I put a UV Project Modifier on a Suzanne. I added an image plane with the texture I want to project onto Suzanne and positioned it.

[image: Image plane pointed at Suz]

*Note: The texture is not showing as transparent in the screen shot because I forgot to check the settings for that in the menu when I used the Add Images as Planes add-on, but trust me that the texture does have alpha data.*

I UV unwrapped Suzanne. The Image plane is already UV unwrapped because the add-on takes care of that. In the modifier's settings I specified the image plane as the projector object. I specified the UV map to be the only one that exists on my Suzanne ("UV Map"). I did not specify an image because I understand this is for Blender Internal only (correct me if I am mistaken - also I tried this once just in case but it made no difference).

[image: UV Project Modifier settings]

I created a Cycles material for Suzanne that uses the image from the image plane, and specified the coordinates to be from Suzanne's the UV map (which I expected to be modified by the modifier). The alpha from the image is supposed to factor between a plain Diffuse Shader and a textured one. However, nothing is showing up at all and although I read the [Blender manual page](http://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/modify/uv_project.html) on the UV Project Modifier I did not glean any answers from it. Can somebody please tell me what I've missed?

[image: My material setup for Suzanne]

[image]

Comment: I've never used the UV project modifier, but I think you can accomplish what you are trying to do using object coordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to select the image to use in the UV project modifier and enable Override image.
Your Diffuse nodes need to be flipped:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to get it to use the size of the image plane? On the model it's showing up much larger, which is unexpected.

Comment: the size of the texture is determined by the projector. Of you resize it the texture,will be resized in the,other object as well